# Detecting Mouse Wheel Events When Form Does Not Have Focus In Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, events, mouse, mousewheel

I want to make an auto log off feature, I want to detect if there is any user input, and if there isn't the user will be automatically logged off. So I want to know how to detect mouse wheel events when the form doesn't have focus. Any help would be much appreciated.
Is it possible, because I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find it.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are talking about ASP.NET with VB? Or strictly VB.NET Windows Forms?

Comment: This is really going to tick off the skilled typists.  And logging off kills all running processes.  Don't forget the uninstaller.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WM_MOUSEWHEEL Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617%28VS.85%29.aspx) definition:

"Sent to the *focus* window when the mouse wheel is rotated. The DefWindowProc function propagates the message to the window's parent. There should be no internal forwarding of the message, since DefWindowProc propagates it up the parent chain until it finds a window that processes it."

The only way you could possibly do this is with a [global hook](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=436321) but I very much doubt you can do this using managed code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Hans Passant I understand what you are saying but I have a way round that too, check if the user is typing =]. I just don't know how detect the scrolling from a mouse wheel, by the way the auto log off feature is not for Windows, but a program I am making. And Matt I need to know if there is a Virtual Key code for Scroll, I've searched everywhere but cant seem to find it. If you know how to do detect the scroll would you please reply with the code. And I forgot to mention this is VB.NET not ASP. Sorry for that. Thanks again.